# Redox Reaction Half Equations

Tags: redox

$$\ce{PbS(s) + 4 H2O2(aq) -> PbSO4(s) + 4 H2O(l)}$$

I been trying to find the half equations for a while now. How would you find the balanced half equations for this redox reaction? Do you just add water for the extra oxygens on the sulfate??? Assume acidic solution.

Comment: That's a possible option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two half-equations are :

$\ce{PbS + 4 H2O ->  PbSO4 + 8 H+ + 8e-}$

$\ce{H2O2 + 2 e^- + 2 H+ -> 2 H2O}$

Multiplying the second equation by $4$ and summing them gives :

$\ce{PbS + 4 H2O2 -> PbSO4 + 4 H2O}$